# What features of images will produce good result used in SVM multiclass image classification?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

I am using opencv2.4 and python 2.7.What features of images can be used for svm classification.I have gone through surf and sift but as a beginner it seems very difficult to me.What are the other feature extraction techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for simplest representation then this will help you.These two are very simple compared to other SIFT and SURF

1. Bitmap representation
2. HOG-Histogram of Gradients

SVM is a machine learning model for data classification.I have built a simple svm classifier.If you have two folder of images,birds and squireels.The steps i followed are

1. Extracted Hog features of Images and append that in a list

   ```
   for file in listing1:
    img = cv2.imread(path1 + file)
    res=cv2.resize(img,(250,250))
    h=hog(res)
    training_set.append(h)
   ```
2. append the labels also

   ```
    training_labels.append(1)
   ```
3. convert both lists to numpy array.

   ```
   trainData=np.float32(training_set)
   responses=np.float32(training_labels)
   ```
4. Train SVM

   ```
   svm.train(trainData,responses, params=svm_params)
   ```
5. Test SVM

   ```
   result = svm.predict_all(testData)
   print result
   ```

Comment: Got an idea.Thanks